# How to use ${var} variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, compiler-errors

I've trying to use the EcmaScript 6 feature of adding variables in quotes using:

```
'Sample Text ${variable}'
```

On the following code:

```
Cat.prototype.info = function(){
    console.log('Name: ${this.name}');
    console.log('Gender: '+this.gender);
    console.log('Color: '+this.color);
    console.log('Breed: '+this.breed);
    console.log('Emotion: '+this.emotion);
    console.log('Action: '+this.action);
};
```

However I only get literal code as String when logging out out on console.

Is there a Mistake I'm making? Or my web browser or IDE doesn't support that feature?

Comment: Wrong quotes. ```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw it.
'tough my title is a little more easy to find don't you think?

Comment: @StevenGuerrero For people searching for the problem the way you are, yes, and by closing this as a duplicate, they'll be directed to the one with the better answers. win-win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use back tick ``. This is called template strings, variables inside the `${}` is evaluated to their value. This also enables multi-line strings.

```
Cat.prototype.info = function(){
    console.log(`Name: ${this.name}`);
    console.log('Gender: '+this.gender);
    console.log('Color: '+this.color);
    console.log('Breed: '+this.breed);
    console.log('Emotion: '+this.emotion);
    console.log('Action: '+this.action);
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Gotta wait 9 minutes XP

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backticks to do string-interpolation `` instead of ''